# D3partitionR circle treemap in R

Tags: r

I have created a tree map circle chart using D3partitionR (please see code). I would like to change (1) the label font-size from black to white, (2) the default circle color to black (Root) and grey to light grey (Sex -- Survived), and (3) format the N value to include comma and remove trailing zero. Please does anyone know how these can be coded in R?

```
library("data.table")
library("D3partitionR")
library("magrittr")

titanic_data = data.table(titanic::titanic_train)
var_names <- c('Sex','Embarked','Pclass','Survived')
data_plot <- titanic_data[,.(N=.N*100),by=var_names]
data_plot[,(var_names):=lapply(var_names,function(x){data_plot[[x]]=paste0(x,' ',data_plot[[x]])
})]

D3partitionR() %>%
  add_data(data_plot,
           count = 'N',
           steps=c('Sex','Embarked','Pclass','Survived'),
           color='N',
           tooltip=c('name','N')) %>%
  set_chart_type('circle_treemap') %>%
  set_legend_parameters(visible = FALSE) %>% 
  set_labels_parameters(visible = TRUE, cut_off = 3,
                        style = "font-size:12px;font-weight:bold") %>% 
  plot()
```